# Draggable effect doesn't work in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the follow code to make the `div` to become draggable:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div')
div.onmousedown = function() {
  div.addEventListener('mousemove', move, true)
}
window.onmouseup = function() {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', move, true)
}

function move(e) {
  this.style.position = 'absolute'
  this.style.top = e.clientY + 'px'
  this.style.left = e.clientX + 'px'
}
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I am not sure why, this code doesn't work properly as I expected.

Sometimes, when I just hover the `div`, it position will also change and that is what I don't expect. I checked the code for several times, but I didn't define the `mouseover` effect.

Could anyone tell me what I did wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks for any responds!

Comment: `div.removeEventListener`, not `window.removeEventListener`. Also, use `div.addEventListener("mousedown",`…`);` instead of `div.onmousedown =`…`;` and `addEventListener("mouseup",`…`);` instead of `window.onmouseup =`…`;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issues,

1. You were removing the event lister from the window, not on the div.
2. You need to consider the offset values to correctly position the div when moving.

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div')
let offsetX = "";
let offsetY = "";

div.onmousedown = function(e) {
  var domRect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX = e.clientX - domRect.left;
  offsetY = e.clientY - domRect.top;
  div.addEventListener('mousemove', move, true)
}

window.onmouseup = function() {
  div.removeEventListener('mousemove', move, true)
}

function move(e) {
  this.style.position = 'absolute'
  this.style.top = e.clientY - offsetY + 'px'
  this.style.left = e.clientX - offsetX + 'px'
}
```

```css
#my-div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div"></div>
```

Comment: Very appreciate to the question. Just a question, by using offsetWidth and OffsetHight, we make the shape to become the center of our cursor every time and offsetWidth and OffsetHight get the width and height and the shape. Is it correct?

Comment: @James, I got your point it always shifts to the middle when dragging. I have now corrected the offset values as it preserves the initial mouse position relative to the div. Can you please check? Now, this should be the correct answer !!

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove the event listener from the div, not the window:

I also centered the div when the user is dragging it, so the mouse has no chance to leave the div.

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
function move(e) {
  this.style.position = 'absolute'
  this.style.top = e.clientY - (this.offsetHeight  / 2) + 'px'
  this.style.left = e.clientX - (this.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px'
}

div.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  this.addEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  div.removeEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
});
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Appreciate to the answer. Just one question. The `window.removeListener` will not remove the eventListener of `div` which means removeListener will not remove the listener of child element. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, event listeners are bound to a node. You have to remove the listeners for each node (div, span etc...) "manually"

Answer (score 0):

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader"></div>
</div>
```